# Add custom DB to wordpress

Tags: php, mysqli

I have custom database that I want to insert into WP database, my database structure is

- ID
- Title
- Content
- Category
- Tags

The table contain about 100k data, how can I add this database into the WP, I try to follow tutorial from yoast here https://yoast.com/importing-from-another-mysql-into-wordpress/ but got this

[15-Feb-2017 19:57:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 256 bytes) in /xxxx/formatting.php on line 1993

Is there any other way to add this data faster and easily ??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
[15-Feb-2017 19:57:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 256 bytes) in /xxxx/formatting.php on line 1993
```

You're getting this error because your code tries to load more data than PHP's memory limit is set to. You can increase memory limit for php in your php.ini, though it's not the best solution, it's better to optimize your code because it's most likely any limit will be exceeded.

For the other part of your question, could you reword it ? specifically try to not confuse table with database, right now I just can't figure out what you're trying to achieve.

Example code to copy data from one table to another:

```
<?php

$src = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=src_db", "username",     "password");
$dst = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wp_db", "username", "password");


// Fetch all data
$q = $src->query("SELECT * FROM posts");

// Each iteration $r becomes new row with keys as column names
while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //Prepare statment
    $sth = $dst->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES(?, ? ?_)");
    // Use params to insert values from fetched row
    $sth->bindParam(1, $r['Title']);

    // Write to table
    $sth->execute():
}
```

Here's table schema for wp_posts [table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts)

Comment: ok so actually my custom db is from my old blog using custom script (made by my self) and already have about 100k data, I want to migrate my blog to wp, that why I need to add that db to wp db

Comment: Well it depends if the both SQL databases are on the same server or one is on remote location. if they're on the same server then you just need to write a script using for example 2 PDO instances to read and write to database. My advice don't hook it to the WordPress code just run it aside it'll be less confusing to debug later